# Can't test LWC component with getRelatedListRecords LDS?

Tags: lightning-web-components, related-list, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-jest, lds

I create LWC component that contains wire service with importing getRelatedListRecords function. and its work normal.
but the problem is when I create the test using *jest-test*
I don't know why I always getting this following error
[image: error when running npm test]
I already follow the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.unit_testing_using_wire_utility) but always still got those module not found error.
and here my lwc-test:

```
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import RelatedRecordDetailList from 'c/relatedRecordDetailList';
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'test/jest-mocks/lightning/uiRelatedListApi';

const mockGetRecord = require("./data/getRelatedListRecords.json");

describe('c-related-record-detail-list', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    test('display_realted_list_record', () => {
        // Arrange
        const element = createElement('c-related-record-detail-list', {
            is: RelatedRecordDetailList
        });

        // Act
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        getRelatedListRecords.emit(mockGetRecord);
        // Assert
        // const div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
            const content = element.shadowRoot.querySelector(".slds-box");
            expect(content.length).toBe(3);
          });
    });
});
```

Anyone facing something like that? can you help me guys, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your modules are not set to resolve correctly. If they were, your test would be able to import the module correctly.

```
// This is the wrong way to import the module
// import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'test/jest-mocks/lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
// Instead, import it this way.
import { getRelatedListRecords } from 'lightning/uiRelatedListApi';
```

To get this to resolve correctly, make sure your project's root directory contains a JSON file called `jest.config.js`, which should include content similar to the following:

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
module.exports = {
...jestConfig,
moduleNameMapper: {
  // Adjust path name accordingly
  '^lightning/uiRelatedListApi$': '<rootDir>/force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/uiRelatedListApi'
 // Any other mappings go here, too
};
```

Now, this should correspond to a file in `force-app/test/jest-mocks/lightning/uiRelatedListApi.js' that should look similar to the following:

```
import { createLdsTestWireAdapter } from '@salesforce/wire-service-jest-util';
export const getRelatedListRecords = createLdsTestWireAdapter(jest.fn());
```

Assuming everything is lined up, your code should now be fully functional.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, thank you for your explanation. But I will try it later. Because I already remove the test first for now. Thank you so much